# How to fetch the last child node in XML file using C#?

Tags: c#

I want to fetch Patch value in last child node. Can you please help me throw this ?

Comment: Please give a sample of your xml

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Go through this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

**yourfile.xml**

```
<root>
<patch></patch>
.
.
<patch></patch>
</root>

XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("yourfile.xml");          
XElement root = doc.Root;
Console.WriteLine(root.Elements("patch").Last());
```